# How to multiply label and textbox and than show result in another label in vb net?

Tags: vb.net

So this is what i have for now and it triggered me an error "input string not in correct format". I am new to vb net.

```
     Dim total1a = Integer.Parse(lblPrice1a.Text) * Integer.Parse(txtQuantity1a.Text)
    Dim value As String = Convert.ToString(total1a)
    lblTotal1a.Text = value
```

Comment: You can try `Val` instead of Integer.Parse . What is the string?

Comment: If you're dealing with decimal numbers you should use `Double.Parse()` or `Decimal.Parse()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try Below code. As a best practice use `TryParse` Methods for data type conversion. Since `label` is not editable, its wiser that `else` code throws exception.

```
Dim price As Integer
Dim quantity As Integer

If Integer.TryParse(lblPrice1a.Text, price) Then
    If Integer.TryParse(txtQuantity1a.Text, quantity) Then
        lblTotal1a.Text = (price * quantity).ToString
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid quanity.")
    End If
Else
    Throw New Exception("lblPrice1a price is not an integer.")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting

> input string not in correct format

Means that one of the two strings that you are parsing isn't able to be parsed.

```
Dim total1a As Integer
Dim price As Integer
Dim quantity As Integer
Try
price = Cint(lblPrice1a)
Catch ex As Exception
'Code for whatever happens if it goes wrong
End Try
Try
quantity = Cint(lblQuantity1a)
Catch ex As Exception
'Code for whatever happens if it goes wrong
End Try
total1a = price*quantity
lblOutput.Text = Cstr(total1a)
```

Those try catch statements prevent an exception from being thrown if, say, the user enters "popcorn" for quantity. `CInt` also works just as well as `Integer.Parse()`, in my experience.

Comment: Parsers are better if there is some question about regional settings. Though this is probably not significant when reading from textbox values, it is more so when reading from files or other sources where the number format may differ from the current users settings.

Comment: That is true, though it probably wouldn't make too much of a difference here right?

Comment: You are correct.. If the user enters the wrong thousands or decimation character for the computers settings... that's just a PEBKAC error you can't do anything about. However, I also strongly recommend using key filters on textboxes to limit how wrong the user can be... LOL

Comment: @Trevor Thanks, that actually taught me something.